# How to download a trained model as a pickle file using Streamlit Download Button?

Tags: pickle, streamlit

How do I download a trained model as a pickle file using Streamlit Download Button?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `io.BytesIO` to store the pickled data inside bytes in RAM. Then, give these bytes as `data` argument in the `st.download_button` function.

```py
import io
import pickle

import streamlit as st


def create_model():
    """Create an sklearn model so that we will have 
    something interesting to pickle.
    
    Example taken from here:
    https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-machine-learning-models-python-scikit-learn/
    """
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn import model_selection
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv"
    names = ["preg", "plas", "pres", "skin", "test", "mass", "pedi", "age", "class"]
    dataframe = pd.read_csv(url, names=names)
    array = dataframe.values
    X = array[:,0:8]
    Y = array[:,8]
    test_size = 0.33
    seed = 7
    X_train, _, Y_train, _ = model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=test_size, random_state=seed)
    # Fit the model on training set
    model = LogisticRegression()
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    return model


def pickle_model(model):
    """Pickle the model inside bytes. In our case, it is the "same" as 
    storing a file, but in RAM.
    """
    f = io.BytesIO()
    pickle.dump(model, f)
    return f


st.title("My .pkl downloader")

model = create_model()
data = pickle_model(model)
st.download_button("Download .pkl file", data=data, file_name="my-pickled-model.pkl")
```